# to degrade the asp.net Core mvc web application to .net framework.so now what all i need to change in the code

Tags: model-view-controller

iam fresher in .net. now iam working in real time project where they asked me to degrade the asp.net Core mvc web application to .net framework.so now what all i need to change in the code. Iam totally stucked and confused.and In .net core application they doesnot used the Razor views

Comment: You need to list out the .Net core specific things the app is using then Google the .Net framework alternative for that feature. If you are using Service architecture than it should be fairly simple.

Comment: There is no straight forward answer to this question. If you find difficulty in getting some things working then post a question regarding the issue.

Comment: yes thank you for your reply. now my issue is that in core application they used middleware for httphandlers and modules pipeline.now what is the replacement for this.can i use midddleware in .net framework? and in startup modulewhere application start that is executing all the middewares here.so what i can do now

Comment: This may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hi i really confuse with startup module.so can you send me some reference code related to that.so that i can understand what exactly replacement startupmodule@KishanVaishnav

Comment: Are you implementing OWIN?

Comment: Nope.not using OWIN@KishanVaishnav